# Why kafka consumer client compress none cpu usage more than compress snappy in msgpack content?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, msgpack

I am testing different compression methods of kafka consumers with msgpack content.

The results I get are as follows:

```
Compress type   Consumer Qps      CPU     Ten thousand message CPU costs
msgpack+none    15000             13.4%   8.9% (13.4 / 15000 * 10000)
msgpack+snappy  29700             21.5%   7.2% (21.5 / 29700 * 10000)
```

I want to know why ten thousand messsage cpu costs msgpack+none more than msgpack+snappy.

I get the flame graph, and I found that `GCTaskThread::run()` and `CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()` costs more in `none` compress type.

msgpack+none:
[image: msgpack+none]

msgpack+snappy:
[image: msgpack+snappy]

I get gc log for different compress type in client:

```
Compress type    GC times every minutes    Stop time every minutes
none             128                       0.55s
snappy           43                        0.2s
```

Consumer client config(part of scala code):

```scala
  def getConsumerProperties(servers: String, groupId: String): Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(30000))
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(3000))
    props
  }
```

Server config:

```
compression.type=producer
```

Question:

I wonder know why kafka consumer client compress none cpu usage more than compress snappy.

I wonder know why `GCTaskThread::run()` and `CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()` costs more in `none` compress.

I wander know what is `CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()`.